# Inconsistent source code when comparing with docs.rs source

Tags: rust

In the below code:

```
use std::env;

use serenity::{
    async_trait,
    model::{channel::Message, gateway::Ready},
    prelude::*,
    utils::MessageBuilder,
};

struct Handler;

use serenity::model::id::GuildId;
use serenity::model::voice::VoiceState;

#[async_trait]
impl EventHandler for Handler {

    async fn voice_state_update(&self, context: Context, arg2 : Option<GuildId>, old : Option<VoiceState>, new : VoiceState) {
    //async fn voice_state_update(&self, context: Context, arg2 : Option<GuildId>, new : VoiceState) {
    }


}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // Configure the client with your Discord bot token in the environment.
    let token = env::var("DISCORD_TOKEN").expect("Expected a token in the environment");
    let mut client =
        Client::builder(&token).event_handler(Handler).await.expect("Err creating client");

    if let Err(why) = client.start().await {
        println!("Client error: {:?}", why);
    }
}
```

Produces an error of:

> error[E0050]: method `voice_state_update` has 5 parameters but the
> declaration in trait `voice_state_update` has 4   -->
> src/main.rs:18:33    | 18 |     async fn voice_state_update(&self,
> context: Context, arg2 : Option, old : Option,
> new : VoiceState) {    |
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> expected 4 parameters, found 5

However this is unexpected. As according to the docs  https://docs.rs/serenity/0.10.9/src/serenity/client/event_handler.rs.html#400-407 and https://github.com/serenity-rs/serenity/blob/a576cc0fd158a29e238ec15034d3919c3b26dbab/src/client/event_handler.rs#L400 there are 5 parameters defined for this method?

If I however remove the `old : Option<VoiceState>` parameter then it compiles successfully. What explains this behavior?

My `cargo.lock` file contains:

```
...
[[package]]
name = "serenity"
version = "0.10.9"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "6275d443266aedf2be507a245ddc23db0c07b1b99774e16f3c879e96a78b067a"
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically linked to the answer – the function definition is marked with `#[cfg(feature = "cache")]`, so it only applies when the `cache` feature is enabled.

```
#[cfg(feature = "cache")]
async fn voice_state_update(
    &self,
    _ctx: Context,
    _: Option<GuildId>,
    _old: Option<VoiceState>,
    _new: VoiceState,
) {
}
```

There is another function definition that applies when that feature is disabled.

```
#[cfg(not(feature = "cache"))]
async fn voice_state_update(&self, _ctx: Context, _: Option<GuildId>, _: VoiceState) {}
```

Apparently, the documentation is built with the feature enabled, but you use the crate without the feature.

Note that this is an example showing how *not* to use features. The approach is not only confusing – it's outright broken in some respects. Specifically, if a crate version is used multiple times in a dependency graph, Cargo will merge all freatures that are enabled in all uses of the crate. So if one crate depends on `serenity` without the `cache` feature, while a different one enables it, Cargo will enable it for *both* of them and compile the crate only once, so the crate depending on `serenity` without the feature will stop compiling.